# Iterating through a redis sorted set to update an active record table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I'm using redis to keep track of daily views for a subject in a message board I'm building. I have another field in the subject model that stores all time views for a subject.

I'm using a sorted set to track the subject views because it allows me to easily and quickly display the most popular subjects today.

I want to create a task that runs at midnight - iterating through the sorted set - adding the view counts for a particular subject that day to the subjects all time views. Then I want to remove the member after I've updated that subject's views.

What is an elegant way to iterate through all the members in a sorted list and update their related (by ID) active record entity?

This is how I'm adding a view for a subject:

```
def self.record_view(id)
  REDIS.zincrby("views", 1, id)
end
```

This is how I'm getting the view count for a subject:

```
def views
   REDIS.zscore("views", self.id).to_i
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [ZRANGE and WITHSCORES](http://redis.io/commands/zrange) for getting all keys and scores into the Ruby land, where you can iterate them any way you want.

```
REDIS.zrange('views', 0, -1, withscores: true)
# => an array, [key1, score1, key2, score2, ...]
```

You can also be smart and use ZRANGE with ZCARD to get data in batches.

Comment: Thanks for this - would it be necessary to create a hash to differentiate the keys from the scores?

Comment: Necessary - no. Elements at even indexes are keys, at odd indexes - scores. Though, the client library could have done a better job and convert this to a hash or, at least, array of arrays.